# ec2 - Current working server in Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2

How can I figure out which server behind Elastic Load Balancer is now processing requests? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a simple shell script that runs on start-up of the instance ans writes the required metadata to a file. Read that file from your application, and have your application spit out what public-ip (or instance-id, or hostname) it's responding from.

Otherwise, you may have your app to make `GET` request to metadata URL for host specific information and read it out while you are processing on it.

you will do something like this

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 > /opt/metadata.properties
```

and then read this file out from your app.

You can see all the metadata options from

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```